# What is the difference between hardware and software breakpoints?

Tags: debugging, gdb, breakpoints

What is the difference between hardware and software breakpoints?

Are hardware breakpoints are said to be faster than software breakpoints, if yes then how, and also then why would we need the software breakpoints at all?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

This article provides a good discussion of pros and cons:
http://www.nynaeve.net/?p=80

To answer your question directly software breakpoints are more flexible because hardware breakpoints are limited in some functionality and highly architecture-dependant. One example given in the article is that x86 hardware has a limit of 4 hardware breakpoints.

Hardware breakpoints are faster because they have dedicated registers and less overhead than software breakpoints.

Comment: Ah, so we can't have unlimited hardware breakpoints! Ok, so even if software breakpoints are slow, we have no choice!! Thanks, the link looks nice.

Comment: @TheIndependentAquarius Technically, you can't have _unlimited_ software breakpoints ;)

Answer (score 28):

Hardware breakpoints are actually comparators, comparing the current PC with the address in the comparator (when enabled). Hardware breakpoints are the best solution when setting breakpoints. Typically set via the debug probe (using JTAG, SWD, ...). The downside of hardware breakpoints: They are limited. CPUs have only a limited number of hardware breakpoints (comparators). The number of available hardware breakpoints depends on the CPU. ARM 7/9 cores have 2, modern ARM devices (Cortex-M 0,3,4) between 2 and 6,
x86 usually 4.

Software breakpoints are in fact set by replacing the instruction to be breakpointed with a breakpoint instruction. The breakpoint instruction is present in most CPUs, and usually as short as the shortest instruction, so only one byte on x86 (0xcc, INT 3). On Cortex-M CPUs, instructions are 2 or 4 bytes, so the breakpoint instruction is a 2 byte instruction.

Software breakpoints can easily be set if the program is located in RAM (such as on a PC). A lot of embedded systems have the program located in flash memory. Here it is not so easy to exchange the instruction, as the flash needs to be reprogrammed, so hardware breakpoints are used primarily. Most debug probes support only hardware breakpoints if the program is located in flash memory. However, some (such as SEGGER's J-Link) allow reprogramming the flash memory with breakpoint instruction and aso allow an unlimited number of (software) breakpoints even when debugging a program located in flash.

[More info about software breakpoints in flash memory](https://www.segger.com/jlink-unlimited-flash-breakpoints.html)

Answer (score 24):

You can go through [GDB internals](https://sourceware.org/gdb/wiki/Internals/Breakpoint%20Handling), its very well explains the HW and SW breakpoints.

HW breakpoints are something that require support from MCU. The ARM controllers have special registers where you can write some address space, whenever PC (program counter) == sp register CPU halts. Jtag is usually required to write into those special registers.

SW breakpoints are implemented in GDB by inserting a trap, an illegal divide, or some other instruction that will cause an exception, and then when it’s encountered, gdb will take the exception and stop the program. When the user says to continue, gdb will restore the original instruction, single-step, re-insert the trap, and continue on.

There are a lot of advantages in using HW debuggers over SW debuggers especially if you are dealing with interrupts and memory bus devices. AFAIK interrupts cannot be debugged with software debuggers.

Answer (score 6):

In addition to the answers above, it is also important to note that while software breakpoints overwrite specific instructions in the program to know where to stop, the more limited number of hardware breakpoints are actually part of the processor.

Justin Seitz in his book [*Gray Hat Python*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1593271921) points out that the important difference here is that by overwriting instructions, software breakpoints actually change the [CRC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_redundancy_check) of the file, and so any sort of program such as a piece of malware which calculates its CRC can change its behavior in response to breakpoints being set, whereas with hardware breakpoints it is less obvious that the debugger is stopping and stepping through certain chunks of code.

Comment: In fact, a good anti-debugging measure can be set using that CRC check!

Answer (score 3):

In brief, hardware breakpoints make use of dedicated registers and hence are limited in number. These can be set on both volatile and non volatile memory.

Software breakpoints are set by replacing the opcode of instruction in RAM memory with breakpoint instruction. These can be set only in RAM memory(Flash memory is not feasible to be written) and are not limited.

[This article provides good explanation about breakpoints.](https://community.freescale.com/community/the-embedded-beat/blog/2012/09/17/software-and-hardware-breakpoints/)

Thanks and regards,
Shivakumar V W

Answer (score 3):

**Watchpoints is where it makes a huge difference**

This is a case where hardware handling is much faster:

```
watch var
rwatch var
awatch var
```

When you enter those commands on GDB 7.7 x86-64 it says:

```
Hardware watchpoint 2: var
```

This hardware capability for x86 is mentioned at: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_debug_register

It is likely possible because of the existing paging circuit, which manages every memory access.

The "software" alternative is to [single step the program](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Set-Watchpoints.html), which is *very* slow.

Compare that to regular breakpoints, where at least the software implementation injects an `int3` instruction at the breaking point and lets the program run, so you only pay overhead when a breakpoint is hit.

Answer (score 3):

Software breakpoints put an instruction in RAM that is executed like a TRAP when your program reaches that address.

While hardware breakpoints use a register of the CPU to implement the breakpoint itself. That is why the hardware breakpoints are much faster. And that is why we need software breakpoints: hardware breakpoints are limited to the processor number of registers dedicated to breakpoints.

I have learned it at work today :)

Answer (score 2):

Some quote from the Intel System Debugger help doc:

> **Hardware vs. Software Breakpoints** 
>   The debugger can use both hardware
>   and software breakpoints, each of these has strengths and weaknesses:
>
> **Hardware Breakpoints** are implemented using the DRx architectural
>   breakpoint registers described in the Intel SDM. They have the
>   advantage of being usable directly at reset, being non-volatile, and
>   being usable with flash or other read-only memory. The downside is
>   that they are a finite resource. **Software Breakpoints** require
>   modifying system memory as they are implemented by replacing the
>   opcode at the desired location with a special instruction. This makes
>   them an unlimited resource, but the memory dependency mean you cannot
>   install them prior to a module being loaded in memory, and if the
>   target software overwrites that memory then they will become invalid.
>   In general, any debug feature that must be enabled by the debugger
>   does not persist after a reset, and may be impacted after other
>   architectural mode transitions such as SMM entry/exit or VM
>   entry/exit. Specific examples include:
>
> CPU Reset will clear all debug features, except for reset break. This
>   means for example that user-specified breakpoints will be invalid
>   until the target halts once after reset. Note that this halt can be
>   due to either a reset-break, or due to a user-initiated halt. In
>   either case the debugger will restore the necessary debug features.
>   SMM Entry/exit will disable/re-enable breakpoints, this means you
>   cannot specify a breakpoint in SMRAM while halted outside of SMRAM. If
>   you wish the break within SMRAM, you must first halt at the SMM
>   entry-break and manually apply the breakpoint. Alternatively you can
>   patch the BIOS to re-enable breakpoints when entering SMM, but this
>   requires the ability to modify the BIOS which cannot be used in
>   production code.

Answer (score 1):

Hardware breakpoints are limited in number and utilize specialized hardware features for faster performance. They are often used for low-level debugging tasks. On the other hand, software breakpoints can be set at multiple locations and are more versatile, making them suitable for high-level code and applications. However, they might be slower due to the additional processing needed to handle the breakpoint interruption.

Developers choose the appropriate type based on their debugging needs and the level of code they are working with.