# async-profiler viewing list of profiling events supported by jvm

Tags: java, jvm, async-profiler

I am trying to view list of profiling events supported by jvm. As mentioned in the [doc](https://github.com/jvm-profiling-tools/async-profiler/blob/master/README.md) I have used the `list` command as shown below -

```
root@vrni-platform:/home/ubuntu/async-profiler-2.0-linux-x64# ./profiler.sh list 10208
Basic events:
  cpu
  alloc
  lock
  wall
  itimer
Java method calls:
  ClassName.methodName
Perf events:
  page-faults
  context-switches
  cycles
  instructions
  cache-references
  cache-misses
  branches
  branch-misses
  bus-cycles
  L1-dcache-load-misses
  LLC-load-misses
  dTLB-load-misses
  mem:breakpoint
  trace:tracepoint
```

I am not seeing the events as mentioned in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53598622/785523) in the above output. But if I execute the above events as mentioned in that answer it seems to be working.

```
root@vrni-platform:/home/ubuntu/async-profiler-2.0-linux-x64# ./profiler.sh -e malloc -d 30 -f /tmp/flamegraph.html 10208
Profiling for 30 seconds
Done
```

[image]

Can someone let me know how can I view list of all events supported by aysnc-profiler for a particular jvm? If `list` is the correct argument for `profiler.sh` then why malloc, etc are shown under list of all events?

**Environment**

```
ubuntu@vrni-platform:~/async-profiler-2.0-linux-x64# ./profiler.sh --version
Async-profiler 2.0 built on Mar 14 2021
Copyright 2016-2021 Andrei Pangin
```

```
ubuntu@vrni-platform:~/async-profiler-2.0-linux-x64# uname -a
Linux vrni-platform 4.15.0-142-generic #146-Ubuntu SMP Tue Apr 13 01:11:19 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

```
ubuntu@vrni-platform:~/async-profiler-2.0-linux-x64$ java -version
openjdk version "11.0.11" 2021-04-20 LTS
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Zulu11.48+22-SA (build 11.0.11+9-LTS)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Zulu11.48+22-SA (build 11.0.11+9-LTS, mixed mode)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`malloc` here is not a separate event. It's just an example of an execution breakpoint.

async-profiler, with the assistance of the [hardware breakpoints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8878716/what-is-the-difference-between-hardware-and-software-breakpoints), can trace access to any memory location. Using the [perf-like syntax](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/perf-record.1.html) for hardware breakpoints, you can choose to profile the execution of any given address in the code:

```
./profiler.sh -e mem:0x123450:x <pid>
```

Instead of the numerical address, it's possible to specify a native function name. `malloc` is just a name of the function in the standard C library (libc):

```
./profiler.sh -e mem:malloc:x <pid>
```

And `-e malloc` is a shortcut for the above event descriptor. If async-profiler finds that the given event name corresponds to some native function, it profiles the execution of this function.

Instead of `malloc`, you can profile any other function as well. For example,

- `-e pthread_start` to find who starts new threads (both Java and native threads);
- `-e connect` to profile new socket connections;
- `-e JVM_GC` to find callers of `System.gc()`;
- `-e G1CollectedHeap::humongous_obj_allocate` to profile G1 humongous allocations;
- `-e Deoptimization::uncommon_trap` to find where the compiled code is deoptimized;

and so on, and so forth. There are thousands of native functions in the JVM, in the standard class library, in libc. Obviously, it's not practically possible to list them all in async-profiler help.